# JPA OneToMany persist child

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot JPA, How to persist child with OneToMany relation ?
It seems child entity isn't automatically persisté when parent is created.

Others relationship it works fine, why ?

Registration Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Registration")
public class Registration implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID uuid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="registration", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="registration", nullable = false)
    private List<Payment> payment;

    private DateTime created;
    private DateTime updated;
}
```

Payment Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Payment")
public class Payment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID uuid;

    /* @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Registration.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="registration")
    private Registration registration; */

    private DateTime created;
    private DateTime updated;
}
```

Log when I try to create Registration :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'created' cannot be null

Comment: It isn't clear which "created" column it's complaining about being null.  You have a "created" property in both Registration and Payment.  In either case, if your database table does not accept null values, it would appear that this column is not being set somewhere.

Comment: In generated JSON only "created" property of child is null

Comment: @Mezoo It seems you are populating your entities from some JSON content. Either you need to set some value for the `created` field of the child or make the `Payment` table allow null value for `created` column.